# Configure JSdoc wtih Webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, jsdoc

I started my Webpack configuration last week, and a problem appear : How can I run a jsdoc generation with Webpack ?

- All Jsdoc Webpack seems to be deprecated or out-to-date...

My simple configuration file :

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const ESLintPlugin = require('eslint-webpack-plugin');
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;

let config = {
    entry: {
        app: ['./src/js/css.js', './src/js/app.js']
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'assets/js/[name].[contenthash].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        clean: true
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        compress: true,
        port: 9000,
    },
    mode: 'development',
    // mode: 'production',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    module: {
        rules: [
            // LOADER BABEL
            {
                test: /\.m?js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
                        targets: ['defaults'],
                        plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread']
                    }
                }
            },
            // LOADER STYLE + CSS
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
            },
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "./index.html"
        }),
        new ESLintPlugin({
            extensions: ["js", "jsx", "ts", "tsx"],
        })
    ]
};


let analyzerMode = process.argv.find(param => param === '--analyze');
config.plugins.push(new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({
    openAnalyzer: false,
    defaultSizes: 'gzip',
    analyzerMode: analyzerMode ? 'static' : 'disabled'
}));

module.exports = config;
```

Now, on my project, it's possible to run **jsdoc src/js/**, it will be generate out folder with all JS Documentation.

How can I automate this process command with webpack.config.js ?

Answer (score 0):

You can append the command to the build script in package.json

```
{
    "name": "your_project_name",
    ...
    "scripts": {
          "build": "webpack --mode production && jsdoc src/js/"
    }
    ...
}
```

If you just want '.d.ts' files you can use `npx tsc`. It will do the work if `tsconfig.json` is properly configured like in the link below
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/dts-from-js.html